# Show ZF2 request execution time

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I want to print in every page of my site, which is in ZF2, the request execution time.

I have already defined a constant within the index.php (which is the first file the request access) with the request initial `microtime(true)`.
Now, where should I get the request final `microtime(true)`?

My plan is to have something like this:

```
$executionTime = ($finalTime - $initialTime) / 1000000; // in seconds
$executionTime = number_format($executionTime, 2);
```

Comment: The exactly answer on your question http://stackoverflow.com/a/32646823/949273

Comment: @tasmaniski That doesn't clarify what is the `end` place I should use microtime.

Comment: The end is the end of a index.php file. So add that line at the end of file.

Comment: @tasmaniski I need to get the microtime as closest as possible to the end of the execution but still inside the ZF2's run, so I can print that in my views. If i do it at the end of index.php file, it's out of ZF2 run and it's no use to me because I can't show it inside the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is *based* on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25400433/2312615).

Every view of mine has a footer.phtml attached to it, so if I print it there, there will be no need to change many files.

To print the time there, first I wrote something specific to that footer.phtml, for example `Execution time:`

Than in `module/Application/Module.php` I added this code to `onBootstrap()`

```
$eventManager->attach(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent::EVENT_FINISH, function($e) {
    $time = microtime(true) - REQUEST_MICROTIME;

    // formatting time to be more friendly
    if ($time <= 60) {
        $timeF = number_format($time, 2, ',', '.').'s'; // conversion to seconds

    } else {
        $resto  = fmod($time, 60);
        $minuto = number_format($time / 60, 0);
        $timeF = sprintf('%dm%02ds', $minuto, $resto); // conversion to minutes and seconds
    }

    // Search static content and replace for execution time
    $response = $e->getResponse();
    $response->setContent(str_replace(
        'Execution time:', 'Execution time: '.$timeF, $response->getContent()));

}, 100000);
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you probably want to add this information to the view (so the user can see it) which would mean adding the time before you render the view (before `MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER`). The problem is though that the view is rendered way before `MvcEvent::EVENT_FINISH` is triggered so the time would not be accurate. This won't be easy to solve...

---

You could consider adding some time related header inside your response. 
[Here an interesting related question about adding your custom headers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3561381/1697459).

- There is for example [a `$request_time` variable for NGinx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html?&_ga=1.162790969.409587973.1462567804#var_request_time) which you could use *out-of-the-box*:

  > **$request_time**
  >   request processing time in seconds with a milliseconds resolution (1.3.9, 1.2.6); time elapsed since the first bytes were read from the client

  ```
  add_header X-Request-Time $request_time always;
  ```
- There is also an `Age` response header field. You can find it [here in the Header Field Definitions section 14.6 in RFC2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.6).

  > The Age response-header field conveys the sender's estimate of the
  >   amount of time since the response (or its revalidation) was
  >   generated at the origin server. A cached response is "fresh" if
  >   its age does not exceed its freshness lifetime. Age values are
  >   calculated as specified in section 13.2.3.

  Maybe you could use it to calculate the time it took to process the request on the server.

You could also add a custom header in your ZF2 application by adding some code to your `Module.php` like this:

```
function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event) {
    $application = $event->getApplication();
    $eventManager = $application->getEventManager();
    $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_FINISH, [$this, 'addTimeHeader']);

    //...
}

function addTimeHeader(MvcEvent $event) {
    $time = // get your time value
    $response = $event->getResponse();
    $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('X-Request-Time', $time);
}
```

---

The issue will still be to get this data inside your view. If you use an AJAX request it will be easy to get the header from the response, but if you don't use AJAX it is a whole different story. Read more [here in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/220233/1697459).

Comment: This is really valuable answer :)

Comment: @tasmaniski Thanks, it is actually also an interesting question :)

Comment: Thats really a valuable answer as @tasmaniski said, nice information, the only reason I didn't mark it is because I used something else that's a little bit different, but thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To achieve what you ask, and some more, in a development environment, you could use the [Zend Developer Tools](https://zfmodules.com/zendframework/ZendDeveloperTools) modules, which will automatically give you some informations regarding your application.

In a production environment, you could instead listen to the [MvcEvent::EVENT_FINISH](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.mvc-event.html#order-of-events), that is the last event emitted by the Zend framework MVC

Comment: I want to do that in production environment to show in every page, as kind of a proof to users that the system is not slow.

Comment: ok, so my solution is definitely not what you're looking for. Then I would suggest you to attach to the MvcEvent::EVENT_FINISH (http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.mvc-event.html#order-of-events)

Comment: Awesome! If you edit your answer for that I'll accept it, I'd apreciate an example too (:

Comment: edited the answer... I'm sorry but at the moment I'm short of time for the example...

Comment: The problem is that you probably want to add this information to the view (so the user can see it) which would mean adding the time before you render the view (before `MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER`). The problem is though that the view is rendered way before `MvcEvent::EVENT_FINISH` is triggered. This won't be an easy fix...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be a really dirty, add in your index.php file at beginning:

```
$_GET['the_time'] = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
```

Wherever you want in the view or layout print:

```
echo round(microtime(true) * 1000) - $_GET['the_time'];
// Use $_GET as global variable
```

*Note: The rest of developers will probably hate you.*

Answer (score 0):

You can capture time to variable in index.php and then use register_shutdown_function to print time difference between:

index.php

```
define('APP_START_TIME', microtime(true));

register_shutdown_function(function(){
 echo 'Request time(sec): ' . number_format(microtime(true) - APP_START_TIME, 3);
});
```